# How to copy a file into another file at a certain position using the command dd?

Tags: files, dd

I want to copy a file of 256 bytes at a certain position into another file of size 2048 bytes containing random data, with the command `dd` in Linux. The offset I have is `144`. I have assumed that `bs=1`, `count=256`, and `seek=144`. So this is the command I run:

`dd if=file1.data of=file2.data bs=1 count=256 seek=144`

However when I run this, the file2.data which should still be of size 2048 bytes decreases. Could someone help me figuring out why my command is wrong and how I can make sure that the file is placed at the correct position?

Comment: Can you copy the part(s) you want to keep to separate temp files, then combine the temp files in to one file?

Answer (score 4):

> However when I run this, the `file2.data` which should still be of size 2048 bytes decreases.

This behavior is documented:

> `of=file`
> Specify the output pathname; the default is standard output. […] If `seek=expr` is specified, but `conv=notrunc` is not, the effect of the copy shall be to preserve the blocks in the output file over which `dd` seeks, but no other portion of the output file shall be preserved. (If the size of the seek plus the size of the input file is less than the previous size of the output file, the output file shall be shortened by the copy. […])

<sup>([source](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html))</sup>

Use `conv=notrunc`. The operand is portable.

> `conv=value[,value ...]`
>
> […]
>
> `notrunc`
> Do not truncate the output file. Preserve blocks in the output file not explicitly written by this invocation of the dd utility. […]

<sup>(ibid)</sup>

In other aspects your command looks good. Fixed command:

```
dd if=file1.data of=file2.data bs=1 count=256 seek=144 conv=notrunc
```

Comment: `bs=1` induces one `write()` system call per byte and would be very slow if file1.data was big. Moreover there is no need to count the number of bytes of file1.data if the whole file is being copied. In general, this command would be preferable IMHO: `dd if=file1.data of=file2.data bs=144 seek=1 conv=notrunc`